# How do I Copy the HTML code of a website to a text file in python?

Tags: python, html, file, beautifulsoup

I have tried this, but I get this error: 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 286381-286385: character maps to '
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
def main():
    f = open("sites.text", 'w')
    page = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    f.write(str(soup))
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: try using `open("sites.text", 'w', encoding='utf8')`

Comment: doesn't work, gives me this error: LookupError: unknown encoding: uft8

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open("example", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    page = requests.get("https://www.google.com/").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    f.write(str(soup))
```

You need to encode (also possible with soup.encode("utf-8")) and use text attribute of response object.
**response.text returns the content of the response, in unicode.**